# Timeline not working as before in case activities after upgrade from 4.7 to 5.1

Tags: civicase, activities

I have a scenario in civicase > Case Types with a Timeline with multiple activities inserted in the following way:

```
Activity Status Reference Offset Select
Meeting Scheduled Meeting 7 Newest
Meeting Scheduled Meeting 7 Newest
Meeting Scheduled Meeting 7 Newest
Meeting Scheduled Meeting 7 Newest
```

Before the upgrade this created 4 activities of type Meeting at an interval of 7 days from the newest inserted. Result if the newest was 1 september it created one on the 8th, 15th, 22nd and 29th.

Now this is not working anymore.

Now if in timeline I put two or more activities of same type with reference to the same type, offset 7 (one every week) and select Newest the result is that all activities are put 7 days after the first. That was not the way it worked before!!

Any advice? Is it a bug? Is it a new behavior?
Johan

Comment: Really it's even stranger: If I run timeline twice it still schedules them all at 7 days after the first, giving me 7 activities on the same date. If I delete the first activity, the one it is making reference to, and run timeline again it still puts them all 7 days after the deleted activity!

Comment: It seems to work ok on the public demo. Possibly the way settings are stored has changed and the upgrade doesn't upgrade them. If you recreate the timeline definition does that fix it?